# Save date from Xamarin Forms DatePicker to Parse date field

Tags: datepicker, parse-platform, xamarin

I am following this tutorial: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.DatePicker and cannot seem to figure out how to get the returned value (date) and save it to a Parse date field.

The error message I get with the code below is "Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index"

I appreciate your feedback/guidance

**Create DatePicker**

```
        DatePicker birthDate = new DatePicker
        {
            Format = "D"
        };
```

Save to Parse

```
        btnSubmit.Clicked += async (sender, ea) => {
            try
            {
                Legacy legacy = new Legacy();
                legacy["firstName"] = firstName.Text;
                legacy["birthdate"] = birthDate;

                await legacy.SaveAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Signup failed, show alert
                await DisplayAlert ("Please Try Again!", e.Message, "OK");
            }

        };
```

Comment: What does the Legacy class look like?  Which specific line is the error on?  And birthDate is the DatePicker control itself; birthDate.Date would be the selected value of the control.

Comment: Hey Jason I added "legacy["birthdate"] = birthDate.Date;" and it worked great! Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Cool.  I also posted it as an answer so you can make it official

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing it to

```
legacy["birthdate"] = birthDate.Date;
```